# Set Parameter Variable Globally at all the backend Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code in layout/main.php:

```
    $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $data = User::find()->where('id ="'.$userId.'"')->one();
    $type = $data['type'];
    Yii::$app->view->params['Type'] = $type;
```

I cant' access `$this->params['Type']` from any controller except `SiteController`. If I navigated using any another controller i got this error:

```
 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
 Undefined index: Type
```

If I duplicated my query in every controller, It works well. But I don't want to do that. How to make it globally at the `backend` only?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't retrive the value from Yii::$app->view->params['Type']  ?

Comment: As i wrote i cant access it when i navigating with any controller, except the SiteController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely accomplish this (without explicitly session coding) successfully by

In your model (User.php)

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        // return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
        $User = static::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
        if(!$User)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            $dbUser = 
            [
                'id' => $User->id,
                'image'=>$User->image,
                'type'=>$User->type,
                // 'usertype'=>$User->user_type, set other attributes too
                'username' => $User->username,
                'first_name' => $User->first_name,
                'last_name' => $User->last_name,
                'email' => $User->email,
            ];
            return new static($dbUser);
        }
    }
```

Now **if the user has logged in successfully**, then you use all this attributes globally (through out the project  For eg in model, view controller) by

For eg

```
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->image;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->type;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->frst_name;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name;
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
```

Comment: this should be more convenient to the Yii way on designing solutions specially when those params are user related. setters & getters methods can also be implemented within the user class. nice answer !

Comment: I think this is the perfect solution. You can use these as global variables in both backend and frontend. I will be fair and accept this answer as right answer and sorry for Salem Ouerdani.

Comment: 100% agree. you can also add setter and getter for `$type` property as explained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html#properties) so you can change its value any where you need.

Comment: Thanks for your support Salem and Jsparo30. Thanks for providing link support. @Salem You can edit my answer provide that link there if you wish

Answer (score 2):

What about using [session](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html) :

```
$session = new \yii\web\Session;
$session->open();
$value1 = $session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'
$value2 = $session['name2'];  // get session variable 'name2'
foreach ($session as $name => $value) // traverse all session variables
$session['name3'] = $value3;  // set session variable 'name3'
```

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html) for more details.

Comment: I see the session solution is good, althouhg i am searching a solution to define the variable as a config variable like in params.php.

Comment: application params are not really meant to be altered. if you set new values to it. it won't persist across different requests. I think global + dynamic and without DB feets better within $session, [$cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html) or by design (global variables in parent controller).

Comment: Sorry Salem, I accepted the right answer of Soheil. This not means i disapprove your answer. I see it is well. thanks

Comment: Yes Jsparo I totally agree. As I already upvoted and commented in his answer I think it is better solved that way. You did the right thing.